# SQL result table, match in second table SET type

Tags: mysql, sql

The following two tables are not liked by any type of constraint.

First i have a table called `subscription_plans` that looks like this:

```
name   | price | ID
-------------------
plan_A | 9.99  | 1
Plan_B | 19.99 | 2
plan_C | 29.99 | 3
```

I have a second table called `pricing_offers`. The `subscription_plan_ID` is a of type `SET` and can only contain values that match the ID's of the `subscription_plans.ID` (column from the above table). This table looks like this:

```
p_o_name      | subscription_plan_ID | ID
-----------------------------------------
free donuts   | 1                    | 1
extra sauce   | 1,2,3                | 2
pony ride     | 3                    | 3
bus fare -50% | 1,2,3                | 4
```

I'm trying to do a query to select everything (all fields *) from the first table and all names from the second table and the resulting rows should look like this:

```
name   | price | p_o_name                                | ID
-------------------------------------------------------------
plan_A | 9.99  | free donuts, extra sauce, bus fare -50% | 1
Plan_B | 19.99 | extra_sauce, bus fare -50%              | 2
plan_C | 29.99 | extra_sauce, pony ride, bus fare -50%   | 3
```

The idea being that it should, for each row in the `subscription_plans` table, look `ID` field. Then go trough the second table and see what rows contain in the `subscription_plan_ID`, the `ID` of the row above. Gather those into a field caller `p_o_name` and insert its values to the matching response rows.

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT subscription_plans.*, pricing_offers.name
FROM subscription_plans INNER JOIN pricing_offers ON
FIND_IN_SET(subscription_plans.ID,subscription_plan_ID)
```

but i get instead of:

```
plan_A | 9.99  | free donuts, extra sauce, bus fare -50% | 1
```

this:

```
plan_A | 9.99  | free donuts   | 1
plan_A | 9.99  | extra sauce   | 1
plan_A | 9.99  | bus fare -50% | 1
```

Note: i get a response with all rows, but i just put the first one here to exemplify the difference.

Now, while i could do the processing in the response on my PHP page, i'm interested in knowing if i get the DB engine to output my desired result.
Do i need to create a type of constraint between the tables? If so how would i do it? I would be grateful for any help that would help me get to my proffered output result (even a better title for the question!).

If there are any unclear points, please let me know and i will clarify them.

Comment: how many rows of this nonsense do you have

Comment: @DrewPierce Why is it nonsense? Please explain if i am doing something wrong. It's not relevant how many rows of this i have.

Comment: let's say you only have 4 and 3 respectively. good news is you haven't invested much time til you realized it was nonsense.

Comment: @DrewPierce And your explanation for why this is nonsense is?

Comment: Denormalized data is one thing. Geez what's the buzz word for this I forget

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have one row per po name and subscription plan.  This is called a junction table and it is the right way to store lists of things in SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Don't know what a junction table is, but i'll research it and see if i can come up with anything. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of junction/intersect table usage.

```
create table subscription_plans
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key, -- common practice
    name varchar(40) not null,
    description varchar(255) not null,
    price decimal(12,2) not null
    -- additional indexes:
);

create table pricing_offers
(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key, -- common practice
    name varchar(40) not null,
    description varchar(255) not null
    -- additional indexes:
);

create table so_junction
(   -- intersects mapping subscription_plans and pricing_offers
    id int not null auto_increment primary key, -- common practice
    subId int not null,
    offerId int not null,

    -- row cannot be inserted/updated if subId does not exist in parent table
    -- the fk name is completely made up
    -- parent row cannot be deleted and thus orphaning children
    CONSTRAINT fk_soj_subplans 
        FOREIGN KEY (subId)
        REFERENCES subscription_plans(id),

    -- row cannot be inserted/updated if offerId does not exist in parent table
    -- the fk name is completely made up
    -- parent row cannot be deleted and thus orphaning children
    CONSTRAINT fk_soj_priceoffer 
        FOREIGN KEY (offerId)
        REFERENCES pricing_offers(id),

    -- the below allows for only ONE combo of subId,offerId
    CONSTRAINT soj_unique_ids unique (subId,offerId)
    -- additional indexes:
);

insert into subscription_plans (name,description,price) values ('plan_A','description',9.99);
insert into subscription_plans (name,description,price) values ('plan_B','description',19.99);
insert into subscription_plans (name,description,price) values ('plan_C','description',29.99);
select * from subscription_plans;

insert into pricing_offers (name,description) values ('free donuts','you get free donuts, limit 3');
insert into pricing_offers (name,description) values ('extra sauce','extra sauce');
insert into pricing_offers (name,description) values ('poney ride','Free ride on Wilbur');
insert into pricing_offers (name,description) values ('bus fare -50%','domestic less 50');

select * from pricing_offers;

insert so_junction(subId,offerId) values (1,1); -- free donuts to plans
insert so_junction(subId,offerId) values (1,2),(2,2),(3,2); -- extra sauce to plans
insert so_junction(subId,offerId) values (3,3); -- wilbur
insert so_junction(subId,offerId) values (1,4),(2,4),(3,4); -- bus to plans
select * from so_junction;

-- try to add another of like above to so_junction
-- Error Code 1062: Duplicate entry

-- show joins of all
select s.*,p.*
from subscription_plans s
join so_junction so
on so.subId=s.id
join pricing_offers p
on p.id=so.offerId
order by s.name,p.name

-- show extra sauce intersects
select s.*,p.*
from subscription_plans s
join so_junction so
on so.subId=s.id
join pricing_offers p
on p.id=so.offerId
where p.name='extra sauce'
order by s.name,p.name
```

Basically you insert and delete from the junction table (no good really updating ever in this example).

Clean and fast joins without having to mess with slow, unwieldy sets without indexes

No one can ride the Wilbur the Poney anymore? Then

```
delete from so_junction
where offerId in (select id from pricing_offers where name='poney ride')
```

Ask if you have any questions.

And good luck!

Comment: Least i could do. Edit performed...added the missing word ONE to third constraint