# How to use an auto-incrementing integer primary key to combine multiple files?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlite

How do you set up a valid auto-incrementing integer primary key on a table if you want to join it with separate files? I get data like this on a daily basis:

**Interaction data:**

```
Date | PersonID | DateTime | CustomerID | Other values...
```

The primary key there would be PersonID + DateTime + CustomerID. If I have an integer key, how can I get that to relate back to another table? I want to know the rows where a specific person interacted with a specific customer so I can tie back those pieces of data together into one master-file.

**Survey return data:**

```
Date | PersonID | DateTime | CustomerID | Other values...
```

I am normally processing all raw data first in pandas before loading it into a database. Some other files also do not have a datetime stamp and only have a date. It is rare for one person to interact with the same customer on the same day so I normally drop all rows where there are duplicates (all instances) so my sample of joins are just purely unique.

**Other Data:**

```
Date | PersonID | CustomerID | Other values...
```

I can't imagine how I can set it up so I know row 56,547 on 'Interaction Data' table matches with row 10,982 on 'Survey Return Data' table. Or should I keep doing it the way I am with a composite key of three columns?

Comment: The primary key would probably not be the 3col composite u mention

Comment: Which platform are you using? Surely not all three at the same time.

Comment: Why don't you just use the natural keys?

Comment: @DrewPierce Why not?

Comment: @Patrick All three columns? That's a perfectly reasonable `PRIMARY KEY` unless you use something brain-dead like Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @CraigRinger Which of mysql, postgresql or sqlite. Question has all three tags. I have no issue with multi-column PK's.

Comment: @CraigRinger nothing wrong with that natural key which is arbitrary anyway considering there is no database, missing data, could just as well include a fourth column called gender char(1). Why not. Gender prob wont change.

Comment: Well since you are interacting with a third party that sometimes gives you data and sometimes not, like a missing date, i would say about all you know that is seaworthy is data for an int key, hence not the composite dreamt up

Answer (score 2):

*(I'm assuming [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) since you have tag-spammed this post; it's up to you to translate for other database systems).*

It sounds like you're loading data with a complex natural key like `(PersonID,DateTime,CustomerID)` and you don't want to use the natural key in related tables, perhaps for storage space reasons.

If so, for your secondary tables you might want to `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE` a table matching the original input data. `COPY` the data into that table. Then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` into the final target table, joining on the table with the natural key mapping.

In your case, for example, you'd have table `interaction`:

```
CREATE TABLE interaction (
    interaction_id serial primary key,
    "PersonID" integer
    "DateTime" timestamp,
    "CustomerID" integer,
    UNIQUE("PersonID", "DateTime", "CustomerID"),
    ...
);
```

and for table `survey_return` just a reference to `interaction_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_return (
    survey_return_id serial primary key,
    interaction_id integer not null foreign key references interaction(interaction_id),
    col1 integer, -- data cols
    ..
);
```

Now create:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE survey_return_load (
    "PersonID" integer
    "DateTime" timestamp,
    "CustomerID" integer,
    PRIMARY KEY ("PersonID","DateTime", "CustomerID")
    col1 integer, -- data cols
    ...
);
```

and `COPY` your data into it, then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` to join the loaded data against the `interaction` table and insert the result with the derived `interaction_id` instead of the original natural keys:

```
INSERT INTO survey_return
SELECT interaction_id, col1, ...
FROM survey_return_load l
   LEFT JOIN interaction i ON ( (i."PersonID", i."DateTime", i."CustomerID") = (l."PersonID", l."DateTime", l."CustomerID") );
```

This will fail with a null violation if there are natural key tuples in the input survey returns that do not appear in the `interaction` table.

Comment: The interaction table is a record of all interactions. The survey data and a few other files are subsets of these interactions so this solution might work. I have everything in csv and wanted to start a database so I'll try postgres first with your suggestion

Comment: You can also store a table that's *just* `(some_serial, "PersonID","DateTime", "CustomerID")` as a mapping, if there's no entity it makes sense to incorporate that into as a unique mapping.

Answer (score 1):

There are always many ways. Here might be one.

A potential customer (table: cust) walking into a car dealership and test driving 3 cars (table: car). An intersection/junction table between cust and car in table cust_car.

3 tables. Each with int autoinc.

Read this answer I wrote up for someone. Happy to work your tables if you need help.

[SQL result table, match in second table SET type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991584/sql-result-table-match-in-second-table-set-type/30992810#30992810)

That question had nothing to do with yours. But the solution is the same.

Comment: One issue I forgot to mention is that I am receiving files and I do not have the raw data for customers. Our employees interact with the customers of another company and they provide feedback sometimes. So we have some flat csv files and not normalized databases since we are dealing with files provided to us from another source

Comment: And since this data is unstable for a database with natural keys that can change, I would go int key. You may go different. 100 ways to skin a cat. Just sharing ideas